# LEFT JOIN but take only one row from right side

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Context:**

I have two tables: `ks__dokument` and `ks_pz`. It's one-to-many relation where records from ks__dokument may have multiple records assigned from ks_pz.

**Goal:**

I want to show every row from `ks__dokument` and every row from `ks__dokument` must be shown only once.

**What I tried:**

Here is query I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ks_id, * FROM ks__dokument AS dok1 
LEFT JOIN ks_pz ON ks_id = kp_ksid
```

But it still shows duplicates.

**EDITS**

- That ORDER BY and WHERE was unnecessary.
- I dont need DISTINCT, it's just what I tried.

**STRUCTURE OF TABLES**

ks__dokument structure:

| ks_id | X | X | X | X | X | X |

ks_pz:

| kp_id | kp_ksid | X | X | X |

'X' are unimportant columns. kp_ksid is foreign key for ks__dokument.

Comment: Remember that `SELECT DISTINCT` works on the whole selected rows, not just the first column.

Comment: Do you *really* need that `DISTINCT`? That implies you have **exact** duplicate rows in your tables, which is likely a bigger problem.

Comment: I dont need that distinct, it's only what I tried,

Comment: @Arkadiusz . . . Qualify the column names in your query so people reading the question have some idea of where the columns come from.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then one `ks_document` has 0 to n `ks_pz`. The two columns `ks_id` and `kp_ksid`are from the two tables. One is the primary key for `ks_document`, the other is in `ks_pz`, is not nullable, and has a foreign key constraint to the `ks_document` primary key. In that case your query shows all `ks__dokument` with all their `ks_pz`. Now your title says that you only want to join one `ks_pz` row per `ks_document` row. Which one? Please show sample data and explain what makes you choose the rows to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT dok1.*, k2.*
FROM ks__dokument dok1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) *
      FROM ks_pz 
      WHERE ks_id = kp_ksid
      ) k2
WHERE ks_usuniety = 0 AND
      ks_data_otrzymania >= '2020-08-31'
ORDER BY ks_rok, ks_nr ASC;
```

Normally, there would be an `ORDER BY` in the subquery to specify *which* row to return.

The structure of your question makes it impossible to know if the `ORDER BY` should be in the subquery or in the outer query -- and the same for the `WHERE` conditions.

You really need to specify the tables where columns are coming from.

Comment: Sorry for that. It was completly unnecessary. It should be in the outer query.

Comment: I deleted WHERE and ORDER BY and it's almost what I need except that I need to show connected row from ks_pz.

Comment: @Arkadiusz . . . Select the columns that you want.  They are all there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - move your `WHERE` condition clause to `ON` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT ks_id, * FROM ks__dokument AS dok1 
LEFT JOIN ks_pz ON ks_id = kp_ksid
and ks_usuniety = 0 AND ks_data_otrzymania >= '2020-08-31' 
ORDER BY ks_rok, ks_nr ASC
```